# How to setup wireless in a dell latitude D430?

Tags: wireless

I am trying to get wireless Internet on this dell latitude D430.

What can I do?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Are you quite sure his laptop has a Broadcom wireless card? Which one?